# Two tables one after another in BIRT report

Tags: birt

in my report.rptdesign, I have 3 tables and all of them grouped by common element. currently it is creating document as follows : (Assume my 3 tables A, B,C)

A
A
A
...
B
B
B
...
C
C
C
...

But I want to have as following : 
A
A
A
...
B
C
B
C
B
C
...

... = so and so forth

Any suggestions on how to achieve this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think, it can be achieved by something like "artifical grouping".

Try to create tables B, C within a one-column table MASTER:

```
MASTER table
[header row]
[detail row]
    group data

    B table
    [header row]
    [detail row]
        b data
    [footer row]

    C table
    [header row]
    [detail row]
        c data
    [footer row]
```

Bound MASTER to Data Set, which selects groups only (e.g.`SELECT DISTINCT groupingColumn FROM myTable`).

Bound B to selection which has parameter for groupingColumn (e.g.`SELECT x, y, z FROM foo WHERE groupingColumn = ?`). This selection will execute for each row in the MASTER table, so consider performance issues here.

Connect property in table B binding with MASTERs groupingColumn: 
In a Property Editor for table B open Binding tab -> Data Set Parameter Binding... -> edit -> open expression builder -> Available Column Bindings -> Table MASTER -> groupingColumn.

The same way for C, of course.

Comment: could you explain if I use Scripted data sets to populate data

Comment: May you explain it more in detail? I haven't understood if you use scripted data set already. If not, it can be achieved by ordinary data sets. If you do use scripted ds, then i need more information about to respond.

Comment: Btw, I realized that my solution renders in PDF output with no page breaks inside B and C tables. So this solution may not fit to long B/C-table data.